# Multiple drop to same location not happening in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have three different images i have given draggable for three of them.

I have a div `div1` with droppable on it.

my problem is theat ony first image is able to get dropped on div , the second and third div is not dropping on div.

how to correct this?

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=Visit+WhoIsHostingThis.com" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
<img id="drag1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=sssecond+image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
<img id="drag1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=third+image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
```

Comment: You've set the same id to all 3 images. This is invalid html, and more importantly, means that things don't work beyond the first one (because the browser is entitled to assume that once it's found one element with that ID, there are no more). Change it to a class instead and you should be fine.

Comment: @robin-zigmond informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 450px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=Visit+WhoIsHostingThis.com" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
<img id="drag2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=sssecond+image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
<img id="drag3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=third+image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="150" height="69">
```